# eclipse rcp : layout a custom compound widget

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to write a custom widget:

```
package amarsoft.rcp.base.widgets;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.ResourceManager;

public class SearchBox extends Composite {

    private Text text;

    private Label icon;

    public SearchBox(Composite parent) {
        super(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);

        icon = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        icon.setImage(ResourceManager.getImage("icons/search.png"));

        text = new Text(this, SWT.NONE);
        addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
                resize();
            }

        });
    }

    void resize() {
        Point iExtent = icon.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, false);
        Point tExtent = text.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, false);
        icon.setBounds(tExtent.x, 1, iExtent.x, iExtent.y);
        text.setBounds(1, 1, tExtent.x, tExtent.y);
    }

    @Override
    public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
        Point iExtent = icon.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, false);
        Point tExtent = text.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, false);
        System.out.println(iExtent);
        System.out.println(tExtent);
        int width = iExtent.x + tExtent.x;
        int height = Math.max(iExtent.y, tExtent.y);
        if (wHint != SWT.DEFAULT)
            width = wHint;
        if (hHint != SWT.DEFAULT)
            height = hHint;
        System.out.println(new Point(width + 2, height + 2));
        return new Point(width + 5, height + 5);
    }

}
```

if I try to use it in a parent composite which has a RowLayout, it looks like this:
[image]

but if I try to use it in a parent composite which has a FillLayout, it looks like :
[image]

how can I make it always behavior like this:
always has a fixed height, a minimal width, can be resized at horizontal direction if there is more space for it.

Comment: I am sure SWT.Search | SWT.ICON_SEARCH not work on windows. so I try to write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent composite can give its children any size it wants. With a single child, `FillLayout` will resize the child to consume all available space. That's just how it works and how it's supposed to work.

It's the responsibility of the parent composite to layout its children in a suitable way. In other words, `FillLayout` is just the wrong layout to use here. Try it with a regular `Text` control. The `FillLayout` will make it much higher than it needs to be for its single line of text.

Comment: "It's the responsibility of the parent composite to layout its children in a suitable way"---I got it!

Comment: unlike other layouts, FillLayout does't call child widgets'  "computeSize" method